# WIndows cmd to change path

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a file named file.txt in `F:/folder1/folder2`.
my current working directory is C:/folder3
how to access file1.txt in a one line command?

Comment: Why not just use the full path?

Comment: Why can't you use the full path of the file?

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /D f:\folder1\folder2\
```

the /D tells cmd to change drives as well as the working directory.

Comment: alternatively, you could use `pushd f:\folder1\folder2`